# What is the tax rate U.S.Gov takes from individual income

Tags: taxation

How much should the person must get? and is it taken from any person who works in US?

My country is paralyzed to impose this tax due to oligarchs heavy influence. I just wanted to gain some knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

The US has several taxes and several different systems of taxation.

In brief, we have what are known as *ad valorem* taxes, and income taxes.

*ad valorem* taxes are on the value of property held (i.e. real estate, though some others), and are usually collected by municipalities or states.

Income tax is principally collected by the federal government according to the following brackets (For single wage earners, married, and others are taxed differently):

- \$0-\$9,075 10%
- \$9,075-\$36,900 15%
- \$36,900-\$89,350 25%
- \$89,350-\$186,350    28%
- \$186,350-\$405,100   33%
- \$405,100-\$406,750   35%
- \$406,750+    39.6%

For an easily digestible schedule of rates, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_schedule_%28federal_income_tax%29), or for the official tax code, You can check out the [Internal Revenue Code](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26) at the Cornell Law Library.

There are of course many exemptions, and US tax policy is fairly nuanced, both in incentivizing certain behaviors (i.e. making primary home mortgage interest deductible), and disincenting other behaviors through consumption taxes (i.e. sin taxes).

For a historical discussion, see the [tax policy center](http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/taxfacts/displayafact.cfm?Docid=456) and their discussion.

In effect, the average *effective* federal income tax rate (which is different than nominal tax rate discussed above) was 18.1% for all tax payers. Which I think is the short answer you're looking for.